# Unzip ZIP file with Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, zip, cordova-plugins

I have an application with cordova for android in which I want to unzip a .ZIP file

To do this, use the following code, in addition to cordova-plugin-zip cordova plugin but when executing it sends me the error and the text: "Oops, you can not unzip files"

```
myApp.onPageInit('actualizarApp', function (page) {     
  myApp.params.swipePanel = false;  
  processZip(); 
});

var zipSource = "http://127.0.0.1"; // Path of the destination folder 
var destination = "/storage/emulated/0/";



function processZip(){
    // Handle the progress event
    var progressHandler = function(progressEvent){
        var percent =  Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

        // Display progress in the console : 8% ...
        console.log(percent + "%");
    };

    // Proceed to unzip the file

    window.zip.unzip(zipSource, destination, (status) => {
        if(status == 0){
            console.log("Files succesfully decompressed");
        }

        if(status == -1){
            console.error("Oops, cannot decompress files");
        }
    },progressHandler); }
```

Error:

```
 Oops, cannot decompress files 
     window.zip.unzip    @  actualizarApp.js:34
     fail                @  zip.js:24 
     callbackFromNative  @  cordova.js:293
     (anonymous)         @  VM76:1
```

Use the following example that I found:
[enter link description here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/513/how-to-unzip-decompress-zip-files-in-cordova)

Comment: `zipSource` should be the path to the zip file (where the file is locally on the device running your code), not an internet url. Download the zip file, save it somewhere, and make `zipSource` the path to that file.

Comment: @petey For example, I download the `.zip` file and the `zipSource` path would be:
`zipSource ="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/some-zipfile.zip"` ?

Comment: yep that value looks better   =)